# Subtotal and total count in table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sum, html-table, subtotal

I will need your support to count subtotal and total in html table (without buttons).

**Formulas of table:**
Subtotal: 1st column * 2nd column (inputs) 
Total: Sum of subtotals

`<table rowspan="0" id="res">`

```html
<table rowspan="0" id="res">
  <tr>
      <th>Bank</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Subtotal</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>5000</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>200</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>CZK</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lm6mf95z/

E.G. screen of example:

[image: image of table explain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a start for you.

firstly, you dont't need that part in your table:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
```

your can add this jQuery to execute the inner function for every event `change` that occurs to an `input` field of your page:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  var total = .0;
  $('#res tr:not(:first)').each(function(i,item){ 

  var tds = $(item).find('td');
  var celQty = $(tds[1]);
  var inputQty = $(celQty.find('input')[0]);
  var qty = parseFloat(inputQty.val()); 

        if($(tds[0]).text() == "Total"){
    $(tds[1]).text(total);
  }else {
    var bankColValue = parseFloat($(tds[0]).text());
    var colSubTotal = $(tds[2]);
    var valItem = bankColValue * (isNaN(qty)? 0: qty);
    colSubTotal.text(valItem);
    total += valItem;
  }

});
```

});

Follow the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm6mf95z/1/) updated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Awesome reply.